# No module name telethon

Tags: telegram, telethon

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'telethon'
```

Installed it using : `sudo pip3 install telethon`

Switched to python3 on console and ran the above import command.
I have both python 2 and 3.

[image]

Comment: python sucks at environment, could you use `pyenv` to manage your python. That problem maybe because you run using wrong python version, are you had more than one python3 installation?

Comment: @mandaputtra I have just python 3.5.2

Comment: Your image says that `telethon` is installed under python3.6

Comment: Thank you @mandaputtra for pointing that out i missed it completely.